# How to access the Private member in the same class using getter and setter property in C#

Tags: c#, .net, getter-setter

In the given code. I want to access the private value in the other main class I read the value from the console and through this class want to display in the console

```
using System;

class Customer
{
    private string _customerAddress;

    public string CustomerAddress
    {
        get { return this._customerAddress; }   
        set { this._customerAddress = value; }
    }
    public void DisplayDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World", CustomerAddress);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand your question. Can you make an edit and supply more detail as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "the private value", and "the other main class"? Which line of code are you having problems with?

Comment: You want to add something into the `Customer` class to get the value of a private field in some other class and then write it to the console? Please edit the question to include the definition of this other class, and also to tell us what you've tried (e.g. have you added a public property to the other class to expose the value of the private field, are you trying to access it via `Reflection` instead) and in what way is what you've tried not working (any compilation errors, exception message and stack trace etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, but if you want to give '_customerAddress' a value in your main form and then display the value with the 'DisplayDetails()' method then the following might help.

Main Form ==> make an Customer object and then give _customerAddress a value by simple doing this:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.CustomerAddress = "test";
customer.DisplayDetails();
```

You should also consider to give '_customerAddress' as a parameter in the constructor.

In case you want to acces a private field from another class and display it in this class, then you should do the following:

Step1: make a property in the other class like you did in the Customer class.

Step 2: Make a another Display function and give to its parameter the object of the other class.

```
public class OtherClass
{
  private string message;

  public string Message
  {
     get{return this.message;}
     set{this.message = value;}
  }
}
```

call the property in your Customer Class:

```
class Customer
{
    private string _customerAddress;

    public string CustomerAddress
    {
        get { return this._customerAddress; }   
        set { this._customerAddress = value; }
    }
    public void DisplayDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World", CustomerAddress);
    }
    
    public void DisplayMessage(OtherClass otherClass) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World",otherClass.Message);
    }
}
```

You can also make the method dat displays the message in the OtherClass Class and call that method in your Customer Class.